# Wait for an object property to be set in squish

Tags: python, pyqt, squish

I am using Squish 6.3 Qt. The application i am testing contains a `QLabel` whose content changes dynamically.
Is it possible to wait for the label to be set to a particular value?
I can't use `waitForObject` as the object always exists and only its text value keeps changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example is from [Example - Testing or waiting for an expected property value](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Example+-+Testing+or+waiting+for+an+expected+property+value):

```
def main():
    # Register squish_dir/examples/qt/addressbook
    # for this example code:
    startApplication("addressbook")

    # This will fail, unless you create a new
    # address book and add a single entry to it,
    # but it demonstrates how to use this
    # function:
    if not waitForPropertyValue("{type='QTableWidget' visible='1'}", "rowCount", 1, 20000):
        test.fail("Property did not have the expected value")
    else:
        test.passes("Property had the expected value")


def waitForPropertyValue(objectName, propertyName, expectedValue, timeoutInMilliseconds):
    """Waits for property value of an already existing object"""

    condition = "findObject(objectName)." + propertyName + " == expectedValue";
    return waitFor(condition, timeoutInMilliseconds));
```

Comment: Thank you..that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Adding TimeoutMilliseconds did not work, so I added `time.sleep(Seconds)` and this worked for me better.

Answer (score 0):

From [frog.ca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783820/10694281) answer, the correct condition implementation is:

```py
condition = "findObject('{}').".format(objectName) + propertyName + "==" + str(expectedValue);
```